# C++ calculator not working as I thought it would

Tags: c++, operators, calculator

Why doesn't my calculator work correctly? Visual Studios just asks me if I'd like to use the last successful build.

Can't I see if the user's input evaluates to a string?

So here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int operation;
    int a;
    int b;

    cout << "Choose an operation:\n";
    cout << "+ = Addition\n";
    cout << "- = Subtraction\n";
    cout << "* = Multiplication\n";
    cout << "/ = Division\n";

    cin >> operation;

    if (operation == "+") {
        cout << "Enter a number! \n";
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Enter another number! \n";
        cin >> b;

        sum = a + b;
        cout << sum;
    }
    if (operation == "-") {
        cout << "Enter a number! \n";
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Enter another number! \n";
        cin >> b;

        sum = a - b;
        cout << sum;
    }
    if (operation == "*") {
        cout << "Enter a number! \n";
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Enter another number! \n";
        cin >> b;

        sum = a * b;
        cout << sum;
    }
    if (operation == "/") {
        cout << "Enter a number! \n";
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Enter another number! \n";
        cin >> b;

        sum = a / b;
        cout << sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate what's going wrong in particular please! (close voted ...)

Comment: `operation` is declared as an `int`. Say it

Comment: I'd rethink the naming of the `sum` variable...

Comment: @Alanay _'Why would that be?'_ Thoroughly read your code again! You are comparing `char*` pointer values, not their contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either declare `operation` as `std::string`, then comparisons would be fine,  or you can declare it as `char`

```
char operation;
```

and do comparisons as

```
if (operation == '+'){...}
```

Comment: Thank you, I also just realized I need to declare the sum as an int. ;P